# “Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range in Swift” from TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to pull the data from chipnumber2 and chipnumber. I want to collect the two in a table, but there's a problem. How do I draw data from two text tables? "let deviceItem: Device3New = itemsNew[indexPath]".I'm getting this problem on the row. In short, I want to draw the data in Device3New and device3 to the same table. How can I do that?

```
class NewMainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var items: [Device3] = []
    var itemsNew: [Device3New] = []

    let cellId: String = "cellId"
    let cellIdNew: String = "cellIdNew"

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(DeviceTableViewCell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {

                let cellNew = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

                let deviceItem: Device3New = itemsNew[indexPath.row]

                cellNew.badgeColor = UIColor.flatLime
                cellNew.badgeTextColor = .white;
                cellNew.badgeFontSize = 13;
                cellNew.badgeString = deviceItem.time
                cellNew.badgeOffset = CGPoint(x:30.0, y:63)

                cellNew.textLabel?.text = deviceItem.title

                cellNew.deviceItem3New = deviceItem
                cellNew.titleNew.text = deviceItem.title
                cellNew.title1New.text = deviceItem.places
                cellNew.titlesaatNew.text = deviceItem.time
                cellNew.buttonNew.isOn = deviceItem.state

                cellNew.tablerow = String (indexPath.row)

                cellNew.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.09)

                return cellNew


            }


             if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

                let deviceItem: Device3 = items[indexPath.row]

                cell.badgeColor = UIColor.flatLime
                cell.badgeTextColor = .white;
                cell.badgeFontSize = 13;
                cell.badgeString = deviceItem.time
                cell.badgeOffset = CGPoint(x:30.0, y:63)
                cell.textLabel?.text = deviceItem.title

                cell.deviceItem3 = deviceItem
                cell.title.text = deviceItem.title
                cell.title1.text = deviceItem.places
                cell.titlesaat.text = deviceItem.time
                cell.button.isOn = deviceItem.state

                cell.tablerow = String (indexPath.row)


                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.09)
                return cell
        }
return UITableViewCell()

    }
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {
            return itemsNew.count + items.count
        } else if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {
            return items.count
        }
        return 0

    }
```

Comment: This would be much simpler if you used two sections, one for each of the two arrays.

Comment: What should I do? @rmaddy

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection` you add the number of  `itemsNew` and `items` but there is no equivalence in `cellForRow` which causes the crash. This kind of design is dangerous and error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `cellForRowAt` it trying to handle a scenario where there are two arrays, but both `deviceItem` assignments are using the same `indexPath.row` as an index within the respective array. But if `items` has two items and `newItems` has three, the `cellForRowAt` will called five times, with `indexPath.row` values ranging between 0 through 4. But you’re using `indexPath.row` in both arrays, and so you’re going to go beyond the bounds of the array for one or both of `items` and `newItems`.

The easiest solution is to have two sections, one for `items` and another for `newItems`. That gets you out of the business of having to figure out which `indexPath` belongs to which array:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return itemsNew.count
    } else {
        return items.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cellNew = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

        let deviceItem = itemsNew[indexPath.row]

        ...

        return cellNew
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

        let deviceItem = items[indexPath.row]

        ...

        return cell
    }
}
```

Note, I’m not looking at the text fields. The above assumes that you’ll just populate both arrays (and call `tableView.reloadData()`).

Answer (score 0):

it because you add items and ItemsNew for define the tableViewCell, you should use just one of them or use a protocol for sync them as well.
so here is the correct code

```
class NewMainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var items: [Device3] = []
    var itemsNew: [Device3New] = []
    var sumItems: []
    let cellId: String = "cellId"
    let cellIdNew: String = "cellIdNew"

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(DeviceTableViewCell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {

                let cellNew = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

                let deviceItem: Device3New = itemsNew[indexPath.row]

                cellNew.badgeColor = UIColor.flatLime
                cellNew.badgeTextColor = .white;
                cellNew.badgeFontSize = 13;
                cellNew.badgeString = deviceItem.time
                cellNew.badgeOffset = CGPoint(x:30.0, y:63)

                cellNew.textLabel?.text = deviceItem.title

                cellNew.deviceItem3New = deviceItem
                cellNew.titleNew.text = deviceItem.title
                cellNew.title1New.text = deviceItem.places
                cellNew.titlesaatNew.text = deviceItem.time
                cellNew.buttonNew.isOn = deviceItem.state

                cellNew.tablerow = String (indexPath.row)

                cellNew.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.09)

                return cellNew


            }


             if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2

                let deviceItem: Device3 = items[indexPath.row]

                cell.badgeColor = UIColor.flatLime
                cell.badgeTextColor = .white;
                cell.badgeFontSize = 13;
                cell.badgeString = deviceItem.time
                cell.badgeOffset = CGPoint(x:30.0, y:63)
                cell.textLabel?.text = deviceItem.title

                cell.deviceItem3 = deviceItem
                cell.title.text = deviceItem.title
                cell.title1.text = deviceItem.places
                cell.titlesaat.text = deviceItem.time
                cell.button.isOn = deviceItem.state

                cell.tablerow = String (indexPath.row)


                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.09)
                return cell
        }
return UITableViewCell()

    }
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if !chipnumber2.text!.isEmpty {
            return itemsNew.count //+ items.count
        } else if !chipnumber.text!.isEmpty {
            return items.count
        }
        return 0

    }
```